# add value +1 in phrase number

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add value in phrase in database sql in database i save phrasr like this

```
DO-2500-01
DO-2500-02
```

now my question how can add **`+1`** in last value like this `DO-2500-03 / DO-2500-04`
this my code

```
$getse = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT serial FROM `customer` WHERE user_add=:id ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 1");
$getse->execute(array(":id"=>$user_id));                  
$getse = $getse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$addone = $getse->serial + 1;
echo $addone;
```

this is my code i get last serial and i want to add +1 for example last serial in database is `DO-2500-04` I want to get this value and add **`+1`** To become like this `DO-2500-05`

Comment: There are a few ways that you can do this. What happens at `DO-2500-99`?

Comment: what should happen if serial is DO-2500-99 then do you want DO-2501-00 correct ??

Comment: at DO-2500-99 i want to become DO-2500-100

Comment: no i just want +1 for last value I don't want change 2500 value

Comment: @WilianBrain I've changed and undeleted the unswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split string, increase the last part and combine it back

```
$addone = explode('-', "DO-2500-04"); 
$addone[count($addone)-1] += 1;
// Append 0 if the last part less then 10
$addone[count($addone)-1] = str_pad($addone[count($addone)-1], 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $addone = implode('-', $addone);
```

Comment: You don't need the `+1` when you explode.

Comment: please check tigger comment

Comment: This assumes that `DO-2500-99` would become `DO-2500-100` (well, `$addone == 100`).

Comment: what should happen if DO-2500-99 then is becomes DO-2501-00 and your code will not work then

Comment: no i just want +1 for last value I don't want change 2500 value if the code becomes DO-2500-99 i want to add +1 to becomes DO-2500-100

Comment: thanks @splash58 for help and thanks for all guys the problem was fixed by this code thanks

Comment: @splash58 if i want to get just last number after add +1 how can to this ??
like DO-2500-4 i want to get just number 4 how can do this ??

Comment: Remove the line with str_pad

Comment: How Mr @splash58 please help

Comment: `$addone = explode('-', "DO-2500-04"); 
$addone[count($addone)-1] += 1;
echo $addone = implode('-', $addone);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115579/discussion-between-wilian-brain-and-splash58).

Answer (score 1):

You can get this based on your requirement.

If DO-2500-99 should be DO-2501-00 then below code can work.

```
$serialArr= explode('-', $getse->serial); 
$serialNo = (int)$serialArr [1].$serialArr [2];
$newSerialNo = $serialNo + 1; 
$newSerialNo = substr($newSerialNo, 0, -2)."-".substr($newSerialNo , -2);
$newSerial = $serialArr[0].'-'.$newSerialNo;
```

If DO-2500-99 should be DO-2500-100 then below code can work.

```
$getse = 'DO-2500-99';
$serialArr= explode('-', $getse->serial); 
$serialNo = (int)$serialArr [2];
$serialArr[2] = $serialNo + 1; 
$newSerial = implode('-',$serialArr);
```

Comment: thank you @Manish the code is working fine too thanks i have one Question if i want to get just last number for ex this code DO-2500-99 i want to get just number 99 how can do this ??

Comment: @WilianBrain `$serialArr= explode('-', $getse->serial); $serialNo = (int)$serialArr [2];` just using this statement you can get 99.

Comment: after `$getse->serial` this variable.

Comment: he give me Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\myjob\almani\test.php on line 19 please help for this write the correct code please Mr @Manish

Comment: can you please var_dump($getse->serial) ? and see what is coming in this variable.

Comment: now he give me the complete code like this nothing change DO-2500-100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115578/discussion-between-manish-and-wilian-brain).

Comment: can you please try var_dump the $getse (one more thing try using some another variable than $getse because it is already an object)

Answer (score 0):

`DO-2500-04` it's a String value and you cannot use arithmetic operators on it. If you just want last counter to get incremented, what you need to do is get the last value by splitting the string by `-`.

Then get the last value and increment it and then again join the array by `-`.

To split and join the array we can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

This is how you can get the last value from string using **explode()**

```
$values=explode("-","DO-2500-04"); // $values is now array.
$lastvalue=(int)$values[2];
$lastvalue++;
if($lastvalue<9) {
   $lastvalue = "0" . $lastvalue;
}
$values[2]=$lastvalue;
$incremented_string=implode("-",$values);
```

First parameter in explode denotes the chracter by you want to split the string same as first parameter in implode denotes the glue by you want to join the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: no i just want +1 for last value I don't want change 2500 value even the number become to 99 i want to add 1 DO-2500-100 

this code for splash working fine : 
    $addone = explode('-', $getse->serial); 
    $addone[count($addone)-1] += 1;
    echo $addone = implode('-', $addone);

why deleted ??

Comment: Yeah code won't update 2500 value @WilianBrain it just updated the last value counter.

Comment: i have one Question if i want to get just last number for ex this code DO-2500-99 i want to get just number 99 how can do this Please ??

Comment: `$values=explode("-","DO-2500-04"); $lastvalue=$values[2];` This will give you `04` as result.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could do a lot of this in the SQL like:

```
$getse = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT serial, 
    LEFT(serial,8) AS serialBase,
    SUBSTRING(serial,8) AS serialIdx 
    FROM `customer` WHERE user_add=:id
    ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 1");
$getse->execute(array(":id"=>$user_id));                  
$getse = $getse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$addone = $getse->serialBase + str_pad(($getse->serialIdx + 1),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $addone;
```

Updated the SQL.

Comment: no i just want +1 for last value I don't want change 2500 value even the number become to 99 i want to add 1 DO-2500-100 

this code for @splash working fine : 

    $addone = explode('-', $getse->serial); 
    $addone[count($addone)-1] += 1;
    echo $addone = implode('-', $addone);

why deleted ??

Comment: Mr @Tigger i have one Question if i want to get just last number for ex this code DO-2500-99 i want to get just number 99 how can do this Please ??

Comment: That would be the `$getse->serialIdx` value.